# Python Typing: Make python func return value type based on input func arguments

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

I have a func, that form a list of certain class instances, lets say it output type will be `list[SomeClass]`.

The output class type may differ depending on data (e.g. it may be `list[ClassA]`, `list[ClassB]`, `list[ClassC]`, etc.).

I'm trying to pass that list and a lambda function as an arguments into another class . The purpose of the latter class is to divide it's list argument into two separate lists based on that lambda function.
So basically what I need is:

```py
def func_A(cls_instance: some_cls) -> list[some_cls]:
   .....
   .....
   return list[some_cls]

class DividerClass()
    def __init__(list_of_classes: list[Object], func: Callable):
        self.list_of_classes = list_of_classes
        self.result_list_1 = []
        self.result_list_2 = []
    
    
    def divide():
        for item in self.list_of_classes:
            if func(item):
                self.result_list_1.append(item)
            else:
                self.result_list_2.append(item)
        return self.result_list_1, self.result_list_2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_1 = func_A(SomeClass()) -> list[SomeClass]
    list_2 = func_A(YetAnotherClass()) -> list[YetAnotherClass]
    result_1_a, result_1_b = DividerClass(list_1, lambda_func).divide() -> tuple[list[SomeClass],list[SomeClass]]
    resule_2_a, result_2_b = DividerClass(list_2, lambda_func).divide() -> tuple[list[YetAnotherClass],list[YetAnotherClass]]
```

But instead of getting output like:

```py
-> tuple[list[SomeClass],list[SomeClass]]
-> tuple[list[YetAnotherClass],list[YetAnotherClass]]
```

I've got output like this:

```py
-> tuple[list, list]
-> tuple[list, list]
```

So the question is how to make compiler/IDE be aware of type of class inside the list and output the classList type based on input argument?

Answer (score 1):

Use `typing.Generic` to specify that an arbitrary, but fixed, type will be used in the various signatures.

Something like

```
from typing import TypeVar, Tuple, Generic


T = TypeVar('T')

def func_A(cls_instance: T) -> list[T]:
   ...


class DividerClass(Generic[T])
    def __init__(self, list_of_classes: list[T], func: Callable[[T],list[T]]):
        self.list_of_classes = list_of_classes
        self.result_list_1 = []
        self.result_list_2 = []
        self.func = func
    
    def divide(self) -> Tuple[list[T], list[T]]:
        for item in self.list_of_classes:
            if self.func(item):
                self.result_list_1.append(item)
            else:
                self.result_list_2.append(item)
        return self.result_list_1, self.result_list_2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That seem to solve my problem. But what is the purpose of setting func as `Callable[[T],list[T]])`. Does this changes anything?

Comment: `Callable` by itself means you could pass something like `lambda x, y: (x-y)/y`, but that wouldn't be compatible with how `self.func` actually gets *called*.